# SQL Server: Acessar tabelas em [Cg]

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho um conjunto de tabelas do "tipo" `Cg` em uma base de dados, mas não consigo acessa-las, tem dois tipos de conjuntos `Cg` e `Dbo`, eu consigo acessar somente as tabelas que estão em `dbo`. Exemplo:

Tabelas **inacessíveis** tipo: **Cg**

Nesse tipo não consigo executar **nenhum comando**, somente visualizar e saber que a tabela existe.

`Cg.Cliente
 Cg.Fornecedor
 Cg.TipoCliente`

Tabelas **acessíveis** tipo: **dbo**

Nesse tipo eu consigo fazer qualquer comando do tipo **DML - Data Manipulation Language**.

`dbo.Telefone
dbo.Pedido
dbo.Produto`

Comment: É necessário que o usuário tenha autorização para acessar o esquema `Cg` ou alguma das tabelas, de forma individual. É uma questão de segurança.

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo que você verifique os privilégios das tabelas com o seguinte comando:

```
SELECT GRANTOR, GRANTEE, TABLE_NAME, PRIVILEGE
FROM ALL_TAB_PRIVS
WHERE AND TABLE_NAME = 'nome da tabela';
```

Caso você verifique que não tenha os privilégios necessários com o seu usuário, caso tenha permissão, de as permissões necessárias conforme o código abaixo:

```
GRANT select,update,delete ON 'nome da tabela' TO 'seu usuario';
```

Caso não tenha permissões solicite ao dba do seu sistema.